# Getting error while serving the pdf file for downloading in django

Tags: python, django, download

This is  my url

```
url(r'download/$', views.DownloadView.serve_pdf, name="pdfdata-ddl" )
```

This is my view

```
class DownloadView():

    def serve_pdf(request):
        #pdf_data = magically_create_pdf()

        response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="/test/angular.pdf"'
        return response
```

The error is this

```
unbound method serve_pdf() must be called with DownloadView instance as first argument (got WSGIRequest instance instead)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in `self` as the first argument to your method:

```
class DownloadView(object):
    def serve_pdf(self, request):
        #pdf_data = magically_create_pdf()

        response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="/test/angular.pdf"'
        return response
```

[EDIT]
Sorry, I forgot to mention you'll also need to instantiate the class in the URL definition:

```
url(r'download/$', views.DownloadView().serve_pdf, name="pdfdata-ddl" )
```

For creating PDFs with Python, have a look at [Pisa](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pisa).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that you'll need to instantiate the class in the url definition.

Comment: thanks buddy  , it worked , but now i get the error that server says the don't have permission to access the file. In which directory i should move the file so that anyone can download it. i will generating the file with subprocess command and then i will be moving the file to temp location and after downloading , i will be clearing it

Comment: You're welcome. An easy place to move it would be under STATIC_ROOT/pdfs, which typically you'd open up for read access.